# What's the difference between <Assembly: Guid(*)> and <Guid(*)>

Tags: vb.net, com, guid

Title says it all. What's the difference between those two declarations?

Background:
When I am using a `<ComRegisterFunction()>` is creating a new random GUID even though I have set it with `<Assembly: Guid(*)>` inside "AssemblyInfo.vb".
I had to explicitly write `<Guid(*)>` above the class to get recognized by regasm.exe. Took me a whole day to identify my mistake but I really want to understand the differences, thanks.

## EDIT:

My program is a SolidWorks AddIn that needs a register function. I just copied the example code from the API Doc. As Hans Passant mentioned, a COM Register function is not necessary but I don't know how I should handle it. It looks to me, the class is intended to have the same GUID like the Library itself. Coming back to my question, could this cause any trouble? Is there maybe a MSDN documentation about what exactly these GUID's are used for?

```
<Guid("$guid1$")> _
    <ComVisible(True)> _
    <SwAddin( _
        Description:="$safeprojectname$ description", _
        Title:="$safeprojectname$", _
        LoadAtStartup:=True _
        )> _
        Public Class SwAddin
    Implements SolidWorks.Interop.swpublished.SwAddin


#Region "SolidWorks Registration"

    <ComRegisterFunction()> Public Shared Sub RegisterFunction(ByVal t As Type)

        ' Get Custom Attribute: SwAddinAttribute
        Dim attributes() As Object
        Dim SWattr As SwAddinAttribute = Nothing

        attributes = System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(SwAddin), GetType(SwAddinAttribute))

        If attributes.Length > 0 Then
            SWattr = DirectCast(attributes(0), SwAddinAttribute)
        End If
        Try
            Dim hklm As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine
            Dim hkcu As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser

            Dim keyname As String = "SOFTWARE\SolidWorks\Addins\{" + t.GUID.ToString() + "}"
            Dim addinkey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = hklm.CreateSubKey(keyname)
            addinkey.SetValue(Nothing, 0)
            addinkey.SetValue("Description", SWattr.Description)
            addinkey.SetValue("Title", SWattr.Title)

            keyname = "Software\SolidWorks\AddInsStartup\{" + t.GUID.ToString() + "}"
            addinkey = hkcu.CreateSubKey(keyname)
            addinkey.SetValue(Nothing, SWattr.LoadAtStartup, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord)
        Catch nl As System.NullReferenceException
            Console.WriteLine("There was a problem registering this dll: SWattr is null.\n " & nl.Message)
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("There was a problem registering this dll: SWattr is null.\n" & nl.Message)
        Catch e As System.Exception
            Console.WriteLine("There was a problem registering this dll: " & e.Message)
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("There was a problem registering this dll: " & e.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    <ComUnregisterFunction()> Public Shared Sub UnregisterFunction(ByVal t As Type)
        Try
            Dim hklm As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine
            Dim hkcu As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser

            Dim keyname As String = "SOFTWARE\SolidWorks\Addins\{" + t.GUID.ToString() + "}"
            hklm.DeleteSubKey(keyname)

            keyname = "Software\SolidWorks\AddInsStartup\{" + t.GUID.ToString() + "}"
            hkcu.DeleteSubKey(keyname)
        Catch nl As System.NullReferenceException
            Console.WriteLine("There was a problem unregistering this dll: SWattr is null.\n " & nl.Message)
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("There was a problem unregistering this dll: SWattr is null.\n" & nl.Message)
        Catch e As System.Exception
            Console.WriteLine("There was a problem unregistering this dll: " & e.Message)
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("There was a problem unregistering this dll: " & e.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: These guids play entirely different roles.  The guid of the assembly sets the LIBID, the guid for the type library.  Presumably the plain guid was used to set the CLSID, the guid of the type.  This information is written to different parts of the registry.  You can't just arbitrarily exchange them of course.

Comment: This means, during compilation every class gets its own GUID? Why do classes inside assemblies need its own GUID? So I guess it's bad thing if I set both Assembly: GUID and class GUID to the same?

Comment: `<Guid(*)>` is used at the class-level, `<Assembly: Guid(*)>` is assembly-level, which you meant to use.

Comment: Hello @HansPassant Could you please answer this question :)

Comment: I would, if only I'd have half an idea what actually goes wrong.  The project template looks entirely normal and fit to get the job done.